# java - regex slow performance without "^" as start of pattern

Tags: java, regex

i had very bad performance with this regex pattern

```
(?s:.+<.*@.+\..+>.*:)
```

in my java application.
Next day I installed java profiler and start trying some optimalizations, after few hours, i have added "^" as first in my pattern.

```
^(?s:.+<.*@.+\..+>.*:)
```

and performance is much better (7 seconds vs. 800ms on approximately 1500 operations).

**My question is why?**

Comment: Because in your first expressions every character was tested a couple of times to find a possible match while your second expression is bound to the beginning of the line/string and when it is failing, no further characters will be checked (so the regex engine fails faster, a **very important** aspect when crafting good expressions).

Comment: @Jan I think you can copy your comment as an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Some `usleep()`, you know...

Comment: @Jan, I cleaned up the comments. Still, the regex is just very messy itself.

Comment: Can you show me a best version? i need this 
`something <email> something-or-nothing:` with any whitespaces or newlines between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty clear .. Let me ask you, do you know what's the meaning of `^` when you use it in the beginning of regex?

> **^** assert position at start of the string

So when you append `^` in the beginning of your regex, you are actually reducing a lot of process. That cause that capturing group *(in your regex)* **only** matches the beginning of your string, and matching breaks if there isn't match.

Comment: Thank you, i know about definition of ^ symbol, but I did not understand all search implications of that.
Also I added non-capturing groups (?s:) for performance, but using ^ in the beggining is much more important.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated in the comments: because in your first expression every character was tested a couple of times to find a possible match while your second expression is bound to the beginning of the line/string and when it is failing, no further characters will be checked (so the regex engine fails faster, a very important aspect when crafting good expressions).
But read as well the comments from **@WiktorStribiżew** he's certainly more regex-gifted and/or experienced than I am.